# Using overlayarea to stop jumping prevents correct image placement

Tags: beamer

I have a frame where I want to show two images on different transitions. To stop jumping I tried `\begin{overlayarea}` `\end{overlayarea}` but then I can't get the vertical positioning correct. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
    \vfill
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.5]{example-image-16x9}
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.5]{example-image-1x1}
    \end{center}
    \end{overlayarea}
    \vfill
    \lipsum[2][1]
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Whereas what I would like is:

[image]

If I just comment out overlayarea I get the positioning of the images correct but then there is jumping between transitions.

I tried adding vspace but it didn't move the image placement correctly when I combine it with overlayarea.

Comment: Please have a look at the mwe package. It offers several example images in different sizes which we all have. If you'd use those, people could actually compile your code.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done. Thanks for introducing me to that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are anyway adding `\vfill` above and below the image, you don't really need any `overprint`/`overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[s]
    \frametitle{Title}
    \vskip0.5cm
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.5]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.5]{example-image-16x9}%
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \lipsum[2][1]
    \vskip0.5cm
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the [s] argument. Thank you.